# Failed to import OVA file to AWS cause ClientError

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to import an OVA image to AWS. I tried both cli and Migration Hub. Nothing seems to work:
I get the following errors:
**Disk validation failed [Unsupported OVA format]**
or **Disk validation failed [Corrupted VMDK: File does not have all data present.]** after extracting the vmdk from the same OVA file.
From Cloudtrail I can see:
**ImportImage** Event --> Ok
**RegisterImage** Event --> *"errorCode": "Client.DryRunOperation, "errorMessage": "Request would have succeeded, but DryRun flag is set."*
CopySnapshot Event --> *"errorCode": "Client.DryRunOperation, "errorMessage": "Request would have succeeded, but DryRun flag is set."*

I don't know what to do and where is the problem. I followed the AWS [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html) step by step man times. Can someone help to identify the problem?